# Getting dynamic width height of DIV or Span with formatted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's pretty easy to get the width or height of a Div or Span that contains some non formatted text like for example:

```
<div>Hello World</div>
```

by using JQuery's width() or height() method. The same doesn't seem to work for formatted text elements like the example below:

```
<span id="caption" class="caption" style="left: 406px; top: 357.5px;">
<textformat leading="2">
    <p align="LEFT">
        <font face="Verdana" color="#FFFFFF" size="4" kerning="0" letterspacing="0">
            <b>TYPE</b><b><i>iorad</i></b>and<b>PRESS ENTER</b>
        </font>
    </p>
</textformat>
</span>
```

This example contains some formatted text elements that display well when we render the html page. But when we try to get the dynamic width or height it either returns 0 or null as shown below:

```
$(".caption").width() returns 0
```

Any ideas on a solution to get dynamic width height from jquery or js?

Comment: font tags? seriously? also, you can't put [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Block-level_elements) inside [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Inline_elements)

Comment: and that textformat...and kerning property! will google it later

Comment: Here you example returns 610 http://jsfiddle.net/55Aje/

Comment: the class selector might contain more than 1 jQuery object, try `$('.caption').get(0).outerWidth();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the HTML code is broken.

You can't have a block element (p) inside an inline element (span), so the browser tries its best to correct the code. The specific browser that you tried this in did that by moving the block element outside the inline element, leaving the inline element empty.

Comment: In HTML5 you can theoretically put block element inside inline elements, although the specs is vague... It is disallowed when "default styles are likely to lead to confusion". So yes, it would be considered invalid in this case, but the general rule "you can’t have block elements inside inline elements" is not true anymore as you can f.ex put a `h1` inside an `a` tag using valid HTML5 markup.

Comment: I’d say HTML5 is more similar to HTML3 than HTML4 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its working. Look at the Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/ZkEyR/1/